# TypeError: Cannot read property of 'data' of undefined

Tags: react-native

I am using `<FlatList/>` to render an item for each object of json. This json is stored in `this.state.json`.  Here is my code:

```
export class MyAppsName extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "App name",
    headerLeft: null,
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      isAuthed: false,
      data: [
        {
          name: "Class 1",
          grade: 83,
          letterGrade: "A+"
        },
        {
          name: "Class 2",
          grade: 90,
          letterGrade: "B+"
        }
      ],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  refresh() {

    this.setState({ isAuthed: true });
  }

  componentWillMount() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <ScrollableTabView initialPage={0} tabBarPosition="top">
          <HomeRoute tabLabel="Grades" />

          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
            tabLabel="Settings"
          >

          </View>
        </ScrollableTabView>
      </Root>
    );
  }
}
makeRemoteRequest = () => {

  //do request stuff
};

handleRefresh = () => {
  this.makeRemoteRequest();
};

renderSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: 1,
        width: "86%",
        backgroundColor: "black",
      }}
    />
  );
};

renderHeader = () => {
  return <View />;
};
classSelected = className => {
//do stuff
};

renderFooter = () => {
  if (!this.state.loading) return null;

  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
    </View>
  );
};
const HomeRoute = () => (

  <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
    <FlatList
      style={{ width: width }}
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ left: "9%", padding: 6 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.classSelected(item.name)}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 16
              }}
            >
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 12
              }}
            >
              {item.grade}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 12
              }}
            >
              {item.letterGrade}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
    />
  </List>
);
```

The error I get is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined' within HomeRoute. I think the error is in this line: `data={this.state.data}`.
I am defining `data` correctly? Am I even correctly setting up the FlatList? Or does it have to do with how I am passing down application state?

If you need any other code to be appended to the question, you can just ask in the comments.
*Thanks in advance*

Comment: What do you mean 'when I define HomeRoute'? The error points to the line of 'const HomeRoute'?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the error is located within `HomeRoute`. It doesn't tell me what line but I assume the problem is with the `data={this.state.data}` line.

Comment: When I define the functions inside the class I get syntax errors. Mind showing me how? If this solves my problem then you can put it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the state in is parent component, causing this.state is undefined in its child component.

When you use the HomeRoute component, you need to **pass the state data from its parent component**.

```
render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <ScrollableTabView initialPage={0} tabBarPosition="top">
          <HomeRoute tabLabel="Grades" data={this.state.data} />

          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
            tabLabel="Settings"
          >

          </View>
        </ScrollableTabView>
      </Root>
    );
  }
```

and in the HomeRoute itself, you need to extract data from its props.

```
const HomeRoute = ({data}) => (

  <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
    <FlatList
      style={{ width: width }}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ left: "9%", padding: 6 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.classSelected(item.name)}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 16
              }}
            >
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 12
              }}
            >
              {item.grade}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 12
              }}
            >
              {item.letterGrade}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
    />
  </List>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Several functions, including HomeRoute, are not defined within the MyAppsName class. Therefore, `this` in these functions doesn't point to the correct `this`. I suggest to put them inside the class and bind all the functions that use `this`.

You get a syntax error because they are not defined properly. Follow the pattern of the definition of `render`, for example:

```
makeRemoteRequest() {
```

Instead of

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
```

Comment: I still get the same error. I am pretty sure this doesnt have to do with how I define functions. I think the problem has to do with how I define `data`

Comment: I see the other answer. I believe that what I suggested would achieve the same result, but since your problem is already solved, no need to invest more time in this... Otherwise, I would have tested the code myself.